# Given that $\int_{0}^{100} (a^x-1) \:\mathrm{d}x = 30$, how can I calculate $a$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I separate *a* from other constants so that I can evaluate *a*? I'm stuck at the bottom line as shown below.

\begin{align}
30& =\int_{0}^{100} (a^x-1) \: \mathrm{d}x
\\&= \left [ (x+1)a^{x+1}-x\right ]_{0}^{100} 
\\&= 101a^{101} - 100 - a
\end{align}

Comment: You did a mistake ! 

$$ \frac{d}{dx} a^x = \ln(a) \, a^x $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $$\int (a^x-1) \:\mathrm{d}x = \frac{a^x}{\log (a)}-x$$ Then $$\int_{0}^{100} (a^x-1) \:\mathrm{d}x = \frac{a^{100}-1}{\log (a)}-100$$ and you want this result to be equal to $30$. So $$\frac{a^{100}-1}{\log (a)}-130=0$$ which cannot be solved using elementary functions. The only analytical solution involves Lambert function.

But, from a practical point of view, we can think that $a$ is close to $1$; then, a Taylor expansion of the last expression write $$0=-30+5000 (a-1)+\frac{492500}{3} (a-1)^2+O\left((a-1)^3\right)$$ So, using the first order approximation, we obtain $$a=\frac{503}{500}=1.0600$$ Using the second order expansion, we obtain $$a=\frac{9700+3 \sqrt{4470}}{9850} =1.00513$$ while the exact solution is $a=1.00505$.

In fact, we could easily polish the root using Newton method starting at $a_0=1.005$. The successive iterates will then be :$1.00508$,$1.00505$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

If you want the analytical expression, it is $$a=\sqrt[100]{-\frac{13}{10} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{10}{13 e^{10/13}}\right)} \simeq 1.005049060013037195011879$$

**Added later to this answer**

It is interesting to notice that, if we start Newton procedure with the initial value proposed by Henry, that is to say $$a_0=2\times \left(\frac{130}{100}\right)^{1/100} - 1$$ the first iterate is equal to $1.0050504855941330185$ and the second iterate is $1.0050490600821571111$

Comment: There is the simple solution $a=1$ as well as $a=1.00504906\ldots$

Comment: @Henry. I do not think that $a=1$ could be a solution of the problem.

Comment: You may be correct, though it is a solution of $a^{100}-1-130 \log_e(a)=0$

Comment: Another reasonable first approximation is $2\times \left(\frac{130}{100}\right)^{1/100} - 1 \approx 1.005254$ and then use Newton's method

Comment: @Henry. You are perfectly correct ! However, if I may, you mutliplied everything by $\log(a)$ which turns out to be $0$. This is the terrible story of one of the most facscinating numbers (at least to me): $0$

Comment: @Henry. Very good point : I added something to my answer quoting you. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\int a^x=\frac{a^x}{\log a} +C\implies$$

$$\int\limits_0^{100}(a^x-1)dx=\left.\left(\frac{a^x}{\log a}-x\right)\right|_0^{100}=\ldots$$

Comment: Not easy to find a closed form from that

Comment: There is the closed form, @Henry: it is the middle term in the second line.

Comment: The middle term in the second line is not a solution for $a$.  You still have to solve $a^{100}-130 \log_e(a)=1$.

Comment: Oh, that's different @Henry: the integral has a closed-form solution given above. Now, to solve **that** equation is way another matter: that seems to be a transcendental equation, so good luck with that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

Rewrite $a^x$ as $e^{\large x\ln a}$, then
\begin{align}
\int_0^{100}(a^x-1)\ dx&=30\\
\int_0^{100}\left(e^{\large x\ln a}-1\right)\ dx&=30\\
\left[\frac{e^{\large x\ln a}}{\ln a}-x\right]_{x=0}^{100}&=30\\
\left[\frac{a^x}{\ln a}-x\right]_{x=0}^{100}&=30.\\
\end{align}

Comment: By observation, you will get $a=1$.

Comment: I think $\ln{a} = \ln{1} = 0$ is impossible because you cannot divide by 0.

Comment: @user3647351 After plug in the $x$, rearrange the equation to form
$$
a^{100}=130\ln a+1.
$$

Comment: I want to arrange the equation with the form *a = blah-blah-blah*. How can i do that? By looking at your calculation above, i have no idea how to simplify the equation for practical use.

Comment: @user3647351 I think it can't be done.

Comment: Do you mean to say that there is no way to find _a_ other than guessing?

Comment: This is wrong. There is another solution in terms of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function, the numerical value is $a=1.005049060013\dots$

Comment: @gammatester Ahh, sorry. I forgot that. Thanks...

Comment: More or less, @user3647351...or using some approximation methods.